# SVG Path Progress CSS Animation in IE - Simple JS Fixture? or use Raphael Lib?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, svg, raphael

So i understand SVG Animations are not supported in IE, i have it working for everything else but hitting a brick wall getting the circular bar moving around for IE so now considering a JS (jQuery) fixture or worse case using a SVG Lib like Raphael. If anyone knows how to write some custom JS to resolve this i would prefer that by all means but worse case need to load the Raphael lib then i guess will do but if the case is to use that Lib could someone maybe help me do the JS (jQuery) to make it work with that Lib as im unsure how to do it based on my SVG Paths set below:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0pkqk5r0/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="loader">
    <svg height="80" width="80" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
        <path id="back" d="M0,100 a100,100 0 1 0 200,0 a100,100 0 1 0 -200,0" fill="#FF1251" stroke="#FF1251" stroke-width="20" />
        <path id="ring" d="M100,0 a100,100 0 0 1 0,200 a100,100 0 0 1 0,-200,0" fill="none" stroke="#FF1251" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="629" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="629" />
    </svg>
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

It is the ring part i guess that need to get working for IE using JS or that lib

```
<path id="ring" d="M100,0 a100,100 0 0 1 0,200 a100,100 0 0 1 0,-200,0" fill="none" stroke="#FF1251" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="629" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="629" />
```

Lib URL if its needed: http://raphaeljs.com/ and i guess a good example would be the clock demo (not looked if this uses same SVG methods im using though)

I mentioned that Lib because its what ive currently come across so far but please feel free to tell on others that will solve this issue or better yet a simple JS solution :)

As i said, its all working lovely in FF, Safari, Chrome but IE just does not want to animate the progress around the edge. Your see how it should be if you look in any of those other browsers or JSFiddle. To see the animation you need to click on the circle for it to start.

CSS If needed:

```
/* temp */
body {
    background: #072237;
}

h3, p {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#loader {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ring.active {
    -webkit-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
}

#circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle.active {
    background: #FF1251;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
    -moz-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
    -o-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
    -ms-animation:  pulse 1.2s 3;
    animation: pulse 1.2s 3;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

/* Pulse */
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

/* Loading */

@-webkit-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using SVG animations, you're using CSS animations. You could use SVG animations with fakesmile for IE support though.

Comment: Ive spent 2 days getting it this far so dont really want to recode and go down another route, do you know if there is anything i can do so i can get the progress ring working in IE as that is the only issue im facing. Happy to use JS for the fixture.

Comment: SMIL aka SVG Animation is probably closest in syntax to what you currently have.

Comment: Yea i read though that SMIL also does not work so trying hard to find a solution, i have just found this though? http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/

Comment: FakeSmile makes SMIL work on IE so I don't know what you're reading.

Comment: Do you know how or what to do so i can get it working with FakeSmile?

Comment: Rewrite it to use SMIL rather than CSS animations.